# Convert a specific column into row names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DF

```
print(df)
    head0     head1  head2  head3
0   bar         32      3    100
1   bix         22    NaN    NaN
2   foo         11      1    NaN
3   qux         NaN    10    NaN
4   xoo         NaN     2     20
```

What I want to do use to use `head0` as row names:

```
    head1  head2  head3
bar     32      3    100
bix     22    NaN    NaN
foo     11      1    NaN
qux    NaN     10    NaN
xoo    NaN      2     20
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to expand on nitin's answer [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.set_index) :

```
In [100]:

df.set_index('head0')

Out[100]:
       head1  head2  head3
head0                     
bar       32      3    100
bix       22    NaN    NaN
foo       11      1    NaN
qux      NaN     10    NaN
xoo      NaN      2     20
```

Note that this returns the df, so you either have to assign back to the df like: `df = df.set_index('head0')` or set param `inplace=True`: `df.set_index('head0', inplace=True)`

You can also directly assign to the index:

```
In [99]:

df.index = df['head0']
df
Out[99]:
      head0  head1  head2  head3
head0                           
bar     bar     32      3    100
bix     bix     22    NaN    NaN
foo     foo     11      1    NaN
qux     qux    NaN     10    NaN
xoo     xoo    NaN      2     20
```

Note that doing the above will require you to drop the extraneous 'head0' column which can be done by calling [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop) like so: `df.drop('head0', axis=1)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the set_index method for the dataframe, like so

```
df.set_index(df.head0)
```