# change a specific column into row names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I see this has been asked in this site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937037/convert-a-specific-column-into-row-names-in-pandas). Borrowed ideas from that post but doesn't work in my case. I am reading some data from a Excel sheet and trying to convert it into Pandas data frame with column and row index. 
The 1st row is a year header with Excel and I have tried to make it as a column header by doing `df.columns=df.iloc[0]`

So when i run `df.columns`, it retruns: `Index([None, 2014.0, 2015.0, 2016.0, 2017.0, 2018.0], dtype='object', name=0)`
[image]

My problem now is to convert the column with Month names as row names. I have tried

```
df.set_index('None',inplace=True)
```

But this returns `KeyError: 'None'`

1. Why can't I call 'None' since this is said to be one of the column names.
2. How do i convert these month names that could be called from for charting to xaxis later? any datetime format?

Edit:
Adding a sample data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AzYmvwSYiPe7y3X1PWCQxW56aZ6VQtTU)

Update: I solved it by `df.columns = ['Month', 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]` and `df.drop(df.index[0])`

Comment: Is possible share sample excel by dropbox, googledocs or similar? Because it seems data related problem.

Comment: yes, just added.

Comment: Can you  check my answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With column name as '**None**' you cannot set it as index, so in order to set that column as index, first rename that column.

```
df.columns.values[0]='First'
```

And then set it as index as -:

```
df.set_index('First')
```

Answer (score 1):

For me working nice add 2 parameters - `index_col=[0]` for convert first column to `index` and `usecols` with `range` for select all columns without `Unnamed` column:

```
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', usecols=range(1, 100))

print (df)
   Unnamed: 0  2014  2015       2016   2017   2018
0         Jan  42.9  47.2  43.000000  43.00  48.98
1         Feb  36.6  45.0  40.300000  43.00  45.92
2         Mar  37.8  42.8  44.805668  43.00  43.00
3         Apr  40.9  44.4  43.900000  41.30  44.46
4         May  40.5  47.1  44.200000  41.97  42.31
5         Jun  41.8  46.9  44.600000  45.70    NaN
6         Jul  40.5  45.0  43.500000  45.49    NaN
7         Aug  44.3  45.0  43.800000  44.59    NaN
8         Sep  43.8  47.3  47.600000  47.25    NaN
9         Oct  44.2  47.0  47.600000  50.08    NaN
10        Nov  44.2  43.7  50.078663  50.93    NaN
11        Dec  48.8  45.5  46.500000  48.37    NaN

df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', index_col=[0], usecols = range(1, 100))

print (df)
     2014  2015       2016   2017   2018
Jan  42.9  47.2  43.000000  43.00  48.98
Feb  36.6  45.0  40.300000  43.00  45.92
Mar  37.8  42.8  44.805668  43.00  43.00
Apr  40.9  44.4  43.900000  41.30  44.46
May  40.5  47.1  44.200000  41.97  42.31
Jun  41.8  46.9  44.600000  45.70    NaN
Jul  40.5  45.0  43.500000  45.49    NaN
Aug  44.3  45.0  43.800000  44.59    NaN
Sep  43.8  47.3  47.600000  47.25    NaN
Oct  44.2  47.0  47.600000  50.08    NaN
Nov  44.2  43.7  50.078663  50.93    NaN
Dec  48.8  45.5  46.500000  48.37    NaN
```

Or select second column for index and remove column `Unnamed: 0`:

```
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', index_col=[1])

print (df)
     Unnamed: 0  2014  2015       2016   2017   2018
Jan         NaN  42.9  47.2  43.000000  43.00  48.98
Feb         NaN  36.6  45.0  40.300000  43.00  45.92
Mar         NaN  37.8  42.8  44.805668  43.00  43.00
Apr         NaN  40.9  44.4  43.900000  41.30  44.46
May         NaN  40.5  47.1  44.200000  41.97  42.31
Jun         NaN  41.8  46.9  44.600000  45.70    NaN
Jul         NaN  40.5  45.0  43.500000  45.49    NaN
Aug         NaN  44.3  45.0  43.800000  44.59    NaN
Sep         NaN  43.8  47.3  47.600000  47.25    NaN
Oct         NaN  44.2  47.0  47.600000  50.08    NaN
Nov         NaN  44.2  43.7  50.078663  50.93    NaN
Dec         NaN  48.8  45.5  46.500000  48.37    NaN
```

---

```
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', index_col=[1]).drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)

print (df)
     2014  2015       2016   2017   2018
Jan  42.9  47.2  43.000000  43.00  48.98
Feb  36.6  45.0  40.300000  43.00  45.92
Mar  37.8  42.8  44.805668  43.00  43.00
Apr  40.9  44.4  43.900000  41.30  44.46
May  40.5  47.1  44.200000  41.97  42.31
Jun  41.8  46.9  44.600000  45.70    NaN
Jul  40.5  45.0  43.500000  45.49    NaN
Aug  44.3  45.0  43.800000  44.59    NaN
Sep  43.8  47.3  47.600000  47.25    NaN
Oct  44.2  47.0  47.600000  50.08    NaN
Nov  44.2  43.7  50.078663  50.93    NaN
Dec  48.8  45.5  46.500000  48.37    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael. what is usecols = range(1, 100) exactly doing? checked the documentation but there isn't much explanation. I have tried the methods by other persons but hard to get rid of that unnecessary row which the year header become a row in the dataframe.

Comment: @W_YY - Answer was edited, `usecols` is filter - columns by names obviously, but is possible pass positions also, you can test it by `df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', usecols=[1,2,4])`

Comment: I think you've provided a different route to avoid the problem having. I was using openpyxl import load_workbook instead of pd.read_excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename your columns this way:

> df.columns = ['None', 2014.0, 2015.0, 2016.0, 2017.0, 2018.0]

Now your command should work

Comment: Thank you! I 've just tweaked the 2014.0 as 2014 as a name of the year. The method worked to set the month column as row index names. And now the df index looks like: Index([ None, 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep',
       'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
      dtype='object', name='Month')

Comment: However, a new problem occured when there's unnecesary row can't be deleted by calling df.drop([0])

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
df.set_index(df.None)
```